# How to remove local file system files created by eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, uninstallation

I have developed an eclipse plugin.
When it runs for the first time it creates some files in an user specific folder on a file system.
Currently while uninstalling the plugin all these files remain on a file system.

Is there a way to delete these files automatically when an user performs the plugin uninstall ? I thought that there should be a way to write some code that may do the job and plugin will call it. If it possible how can i do this ?

Regards,
Slavik.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide touchpoint instructions that run during install/uninstall.  The instructions are provided as metadata to p2 repositories created as part of your build.  The default instructions do provide a remove/rmdir.

If the user gets to specify where the files are stored, though, then you can't know at build time and you would have to write your own "native touchpoint" so you could track down the files.  See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html for more information.